# file setprecision c++ code

Tags: c++, file

I had this code in C++ that is working just fine, first it ask the user for a
file name, and then saves some number in that file.

But what I am trying to do is to save numbers with two decimal places, e.g the
user types `2` and I want to save the number `2`, but with two decimal places
`2.00`.

Any ideas of how to do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double num;
  double data;
  string fileName = " ";
  cout << "File name: " << endl;
  getline(cin, fileName);
  cout << "How many numbers do you want to insert? ";
  cin >> num;
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::app);
    cout << "Num " << i << ": ";
    cin >> data;
    myfile << data << setprecision(3) << endl;
    myfile.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `setprecision()` *after* writing `data`?

Comment: @nobar: you should probably make that an answer since that is almost certainly the problem here.

Comment: I don't know, just trying to fin a way to do it :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, you need to use `setprecision` before the data is written.

I would also move the open and close of the file out of the loop (and the declaration of `myfile`, of course, as it's generally a fairly "heavy" operation to open and close a file inside a loop like this.

Here's a little demo that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream f("a.txt", std::ios::app);
    double d = 3.1415926;

    f << "Test 1 " << std::setprecision(5) << d << std::endl;

    f << "Test 2 " << d << std::endl;

    f << std::setprecision(7);
    f << "Test 3 " << d << std::endl;

    f.precision(3); 
    f << "Test 3 " << d << std::endl;

    f.close();


}
```

Note however that if your number is for example 3.0, then you also need `std::fixed`. E.g. if we do this:

```
    f << "Test 1 " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << d << std::endl;
```

it will show 3.00000

Comment: ofstream myfile;
for(int i=1; i<=num; i++)
{

myfile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::app);
cout<<"Num "<< i <<": ";
cout<<setpresition(2);
std::cout<<std::setprecision(3)<<endl;
cin>>data;
myfile<<data<<endl;

}myfile.close();

I modify my code and now look like this, but I still gt the same :/

Comment: @user3214262 `setprecision()` is stream-specific. If you want it to apply to `myfile`, you have to apply it to `myfile`, not to `std::cout`.

Comment: Thanks Mats Petersson